# How display a String out of the Struct Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, struct

I want to display a String in a separate function and just call the function when the user choose the wrong answer, the problem is when I create the function and I try to use it my app crash and is telling me an error about the index is out of range..... any suggestion how can I fix this? or a recommendation to do a better and clean job? Here is my code:

```
//This is my struct
struct Question {
var Question: String!
var Answers: [String]!
var Answer: Int!
var Img: UIImage!
var Info: String!
} 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//Here the way I display the questions
questions = [

        Question(
            Question: "Question #1",
            Answers: ["A","B","C","D"],
            Answer: 1,
            Img: UIImage.self(named: "steve"),
            Info: "Steve"
                ),
]

//Here is my function that I want to create to display the Info:
private function showInformation() {
infoLabel.text = questions[Question].Info
}
```

Ps: If need more details let me know, by the way my function to create a random question is this

```
private func pickingRandomQuestion() {
    if questions.count > 0  {
        questionNumber = random() % questions.count //This make a random pick of Question
        questionLabel.text = questions[questionNumber].Question //Converting quesitonLabel into TEXT
        answerNumber = questions[questionNumber].Answer
        imgDisplay.image = questions[questionNumber].Img

//Im trying to use one of this examples to display but is not working :(

        answerA.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[0], forState: .Normal)
        answerB.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[1], forState: .Normal)
        answerC.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[2], forState: .Normal)
        answerD.setTitle(questions[questionNumber].Answers[3], forState: .Normal)

        questions.removeAtIndex(questionNumber)
    } else {

        finishGame.hidden = false
        answerA.hidden = true
        answerB.hidden = true
        answerC.hidden = true
        answerD.hidden = true

    }
}
```

Comment: how about `"infoLabel.text = questions[Question]?[Info]!`"  You could also try `"infoLabel.text = questions.valueForKeyPath("Question.Info")!`"

Comment: do i use "" or without ""?

Comment: you do need quotes for the keys.  So:  "`infoLabel.text = questions["Question"]?["Info"]!`".  Don't include the outside edge quotes which I only included to illustrate where the code starts.  I found this information [in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475463/how-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries-in-swift).

Comment: its not working I already read the post and is not working, im so sad right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your question's info in a property before you remove the question from the array of questions.

Add a property to your class:

```
var questionInfo = ""
```

In `pickingRandomQuestion` set the value before calling `removeAtIndex`:

```
questionInfo = questions[questionNumber].Info
```

Then use the property value in `showInformation`:

```
private function showInformation() {
    infoLabel.text = questionInfo
}
```

Comment: Your struct fields should really start with a lowercase letter.  Only class names and struct names should start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: If your question struct is only used as shown, there is not need to make the properties `var` and declare the without the `!`.  Why use implicitly unwrapped optionals if you're never planning on initializing them to `nil`?

Comment: Im new in swift sorry for some of the code is bad but thank you so much for the answer and i learn something new now, thank you again for the second advice you the best !!