# swift 4 set subkey of dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift4

I would like to set the value of a key of a key in swift 4. Is this possible?

For example if we have

```
var d:[String:Any] = [:]
```

I see there is a function 'updateValue'

```
d.updateValue([:], forKey: "a")
```

But what I want to be able to do is:

```
d.updateValue([:], forKey: "a.b.c")
```

which would be expected to resolve to

```
{"a" : { "b" : { "c" : {} }
```

instead of

```
{"a.b.c" : {} }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary does not support this out the box but you could use keypaths. 
https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/dictionary-key-paths/

Your best bet is to create nested dictionaries or a custom JSON type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475702/3705470