# How to get key of multiple keys in json array and manipulate their data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

I want to fetch the nested key and manipulates their data.
I have tried 2 methods:

```
Example 1: 
    for (let key in the dictionary) {
        for (let keys in dictionary[key]) {
            console.log(keys) 
        }
    }
Example 2:
 for (let key in dictionary) {
     for (let k in lng.dictionary[key]["data"]) {
         console.log(k)
     }
 }
```

> In Example 1, I am getting both the keys `name` and `data`.
>
> In Example 2,I am getting only a, b, c, d, yes, no, f, hgs, cft, vit. not 
>   their values.

But I want to:

> 1. Fetch only data.
> 2. and manipulate their values like `{"key":"a","value":"some text"},{"key":"b","value":"some text"},{"key":"c","value":"c for"},{},{}`.

here is my Json object

```
"dictionary" : {
                    "bar" : {
                            "name" : "Bar",
                            "data" : {
                                    "a" : "some text",
                                    "b" : "some text",
                                    "c" : "c for",
                                    "d" : "some text",
                                    "yes" : "true",
                                    "No" : "true",
                                    "f" : "some text"
                            }
                    },
                    "text" : {
                            "name" : "Text",
                            "data" : {
                                    "hgs" : "some text",
                                    "cft" : "some text",
                                    "vit" : "some text"
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: You should probably check `Object.entries`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475463/how-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access deeply nested dictionaries in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475463/how-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** to extract the inner `data` object and for each `key` and `value` of the `data` object which can be iterated by **[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries)** we would form a `temp` object.

Using **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** we can accumulate the `temp` objects into an array.

```js
const data = {"dictionary":{"bar":{"name":"Bar","data":{"a":"some text","b":"some text","c":"c for","d":"some text","yes":"true","No":"true","f":"some text"}},"text":{"name":"Text","data":{"hgs":"some text","cft":"some text","vit":"some text"}}}};

const dataProcessed = Object.values(data.dictionary).reduce((acc, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj.data).forEach(([key, value])=>{
    temp = {};
    temp["key"] = key;
    temp["value"] = value;
    acc.push(temp);
  });
return acc;
}, []);
console.log(dataProcessed);
```