# Adding key value pair in dictionary swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Given this

```
var applicationPayload =
    [
        "main": [
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": [
                "inside1": "insideValue1"
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

How can I append or add something inside key2 property.. I'd like the result to be something like this

```
[
    "main": [
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": [
            "newInside2": "newInsideValue2",
            "inside1": "insideValue1"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried doing this does not seems to work

```
applicationPayload["main"]["key2"]["newInside2"] = "newInsideValue2"
```

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475463/how-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries-in-swift). Main thing you need to know is that nested value lookup yields an optional constant by default. To make sure Xcode suggests possible code completion and to keep things clear make sure you declare a concrete type for the dictionary variable, such as `[String: [String: [String: String]]]`.

Comment: To avoid making code unnecessarily complex and error-prone — access the key you need and write it to a variable, then add necessary variables and write it back to the original dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for easy access/assign with `keyPath`

```
   // get value of key2
 var res = applicationPayload[keyPath:"main.key2"] as! [String:Any]
   // add the other key
 res["newInside2"] = "newInsideValue2"
   // mutate key2
 applicationPayload[keyPath:"main.key2"] = res
```

For more about keypaths check https://oleb.net/blog/2017/01/dictionary-key-paths/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable containing the current value of `key2` and modify that before rewriting it back into the original dictionary:

```
import Foundation

var applicationPayload =
    [
        "main": [
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": [
                "inside1": "insideValue1"
            ]
        ]
    ]

print("Before: \(applicationPayload)")

var key2Value = applicationPayload["main"]?["key2"] as! [String: String]
key2Value["newInside2"] = "newInsideValue2"
applicationPayload["main"]?["key2"] = key2Value

print("After: \(applicationPayload)")
```

**Output:**

```
Before: ["main": ["key1": "value1", "key2": ["inside1": "insideValue1"]]]
After: ["main": ["key1": "value1", "key2": ["inside1": "insideValue1", "newInside2": "newInsideValue2"]]]
```